# Send xml or json from socket.io in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, sockets

a web service consumer soap in my node.js server now want to send me the xml returned by the web service to my clients through socket.io ............... please help as I do 
Here I give you the code that I have so far

```
var ws = require('ws.js')
  , Http = ws.Http
  , Security = ws.Security
  , UsernameToken = ws.UsernameToken;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8124);
//**********************************************************************//
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('datos', function (data2,data3) {
    console.log('datos recibidos...: ', data2,data3);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var request =  '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                  '<Header />' +
                    '<Body>' +
                      '<sumar xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
                        '<a>'+data2+'</a>' +
                        '<b>'+data3+'</b>' +
                      '</sumar>' +
                    '</Body>' +
                '</Envelope>'

          var ctx =  { request: request 
                     , url: "http://gmlppc01ronny/WebPruebayo/Service1.asmx?op=sumar"
                     , action: "http://tempuri.org/sumar"
                     , contentType: "text/xml" 
                     };
          var handlers =  [new Http()
                          ]
          ws.send(handlers, ctx, function(ctx) {                    
            console.log("response: " + ctx.response);
           var respues = ctx.response;
             /////////////////////////////         
             }); 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var data= ctx.response;
    socket.volatile.emit('datosrecibidos', data);
 });

});


and my client

socket.on('datosrecibidos', function (data) {

     var data4 = document.write(XML.stringfy(data));
     console.log(data4);
     $('#resultado').append(data);
  });
```

Comment: You probably need to move `var data= ctx.response;` and `socket.volatile.emit('datosrecibidos', data);` inside the callback for `ws.send`

Comment: thank's ..... if I did just that and was solved thanks anyway